# How to disable radio button After 1 Click

Tags: javascript, html

JS :

```
   function checkValue(option) {
        if (option == "4") {

            alert("Correct");

            var pop = parseInt(window.name++);
            alert(pop);
            window.location="q2.html";
        }
        else {
            alert("False, Option (4) is the Correct Answer.");
            window.location="q2.html";
        }
    }
```

Html :

```
<html>

 <input type="radio" name="option_1" value="1" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Text Markup Languages <br /> <br />
    <input type="radio" name="option_2" value="2" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Highest Text Markup Language <br /> <br />
    <input type="radio" name="option_3" value="3" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Total Markup Language <br /> <br />
   <input type="radio" name="option_4" value="4" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Text Markup Language <br /> <br />

</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Post related code and describe your problem with more details.

Comment: 1. <input type="radio" name="option_1" value="1" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Text Markup Languages <br /> <br />
    2. <input type="radio" name="option_2" value="2" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Highest Text Markup Language <br /> <br />
    3. <input type="radio" name="option_3" value="3" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Total Markup Language <br /> <br />
    4. <input type="radio" name="option_4" value="4" onclick="checkValue(this.value);" /> Hyper Text Markup Language <br /> <br />

Comment: Please update your question with additional code.

Comment: Sorry, I think we're all a little confused. If you could edit your post to include what you would like to happen (the expected outcome), and what is currently happening, it would be easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: @haxtbh and others Kindly wait

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2118c0177ef3836f8bfd.git

Comment: Just tell us what you try to do? you redirect the user after he click on the radio button so we don't see what need to disable..

Comment: actually window.name = 1; is increasing number after window.name++ but i want user to just one click , because if user click so window.name++ would be 2 on this page and that is i dont want. Kindly guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, I'd clean up the HTML code a bit... I assume the four radio buttons are all possible answers to one question, in which case they should all have the same name (not value) so that you can only choose one answer; then in the script I'd would need to use more information than just the value of the checked answer, so instead of sending `this.value` to the function, I'd just send `this`:

```
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="option_1" onclick="checkValue(this);" /> Hyper Text Markup Languages <br /> <br />
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="option_2" onclick="checkValue(this);" /> Highest Text Markup Language <br /> <br />
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="option_3" onclick="checkValue(this);" /> Hyper Total Markup Language <br /> <br />
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="option_4" onclick="checkValue(this);" /> Hyper Text Markup Language <br /> <br />
```

In the script, to disable the radio buttons after they've been clicked, I would add a function that goes through each radio button that has the same name (as mentioned above) as the one that's been clicked, and disable it:

```
var radiobuttons = document.getElementsByName(option.name);
for(i = 0; i < radiobuttons.length; i++) {
    radiobuttons[i].disabled = true;
}
```

Then, of course, the alert to let the visitor know whether they've got the right answer:

```
if (option.value == "option_4") {
    alert("Correct");
} else {
    alert("False, Option (4) is the Correct Answer.");
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Niffler/nyqk6gga/

(I'm assuming you don't want to use jQuery; otherwise there would be much nicer-looking ways to do this...)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).delegate(".rndmyradio","click",function () {
    $(this).hide();
  
  //if you want values of selected
    alert($(this).val());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="rndmyradio" type="radio" name="option_1" value="1"  /> <label>Hyper Text Markup Languages </label><br /> <br /> 
2. <input class="rndmyradio" type="radio" name="option_2" value="2"  /> Highest Text Markup Language <br /> <br /> 
3. <input class="rndmyradio" type="radio" name="option_3" value="3"  /> Hyper Total Markup Language <br /> <br />
4. <input class="rndmyradio" type="radio" name="option_4" value="4" /> Hyper Text Markup Language <br /> <br />
```

Comment: Thanks @Rutunj sheladiya Awesome Work but my i want another think i have to upload with details.

Comment: please set your question properly so anybody can give answer 
check what you want on selection on radio button either you select and disable or redirect to another page

Comment: sheladia   you got it ?

Comment: this is really confusing us
not getting any thing yet give discription